# Why can I not remove the appended elements that has a class name call building-x?

Tags: javascript

For some reason I can not remove any of the building-x elements that JavaScript generates. So I'm wondering why?

So I change my code a bit and I ended up adding building-x to the HTML to see if that will do the trick and as soon as I did that, it removed the generated HTML version of building-x but I still can not remove the generated JavaScript version of building-x.

What would I have to do to also be able to remove the JavaScript generated version of building-x?

**Here is my code**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

/*<Add another building>*/

document.querySelector('#add-another-building').addEventListener('click',addAnotherBuilding);

function addAnotherBuilding(){

if(document.querySelector(".building-x")){
document.querySelector(".building-x").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<div class='building-x'></div>");
}

else{
document.querySelector("#first-building").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<div class='building-x'></div>");
}

}

/*</Add another building>*/

/*<Remove the targeted buildingX>*/

if(document.querySelector('.building-x')){

var buildingXs= document.querySelectorAll('.building-x');

for(var i=0; i < buildingXs.length; i++){
buildingXs[i].addEventListener('click',removeTheTargetedBuildingX);
}

function removeTheTargetedBuildingX(event){
var removeTheTargetedBuildingX = event.currentTarget;
removeTheTargetedBuildingX.parentNode.removeChild(removeTheTargetedBuildingX);
}
}

/*</Remove the targeted buildingX>*/

});
```

```css
#buildings{
  background-color: gray;
}

#first-building{
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#add-another-building{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: block;
}

.building-x{
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id='add-another-building'>Add another building</button>

<div id='buildings'>

<div id='first-building'></div><!--</first-building>-->

<div class='building-x'></div><!--</building-x>-->

</div><!--</buildings>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem was that the part of the code that adds listeners was only run once at the beginning, when there were no building-x. Thus no js-generated building-x ever got a listener.

When you added a starting html building-x, that one got a listener but not subsequent js-generated building-x.

The solution is to call the add-listener code after adding a js-building x. In the below example, I have removed the html-starting building-x.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

    /*<Add another building>*/

    document.querySelector('#add-another-building').addEventListener('click',addAnotherBuilding);

    function addAnotherBuilding(){

        if(document.querySelector(".building-x")){
            document.querySelector(".building-x").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<div class='building-x'></div>");
        }

        else{
            document.querySelector("#first-building").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<div class='building-x'></div>");
        }
        addListener();
    }

    /*</Add another building>*/

    /*<Remove the targeted buildingX>*/

    function addListener() {
        var buildingXs = document.querySelectorAll('.building-x');

        for(var i=0; i < buildingXs.length; i++){
            if (buildingXs[i].classList.contains("listening") === false) {
                buildingXs[i].addEventListener('click',removeTheTargetedBuildingX);
                buildingXs[i].classList.add("listening");
            }
        }
    }


    function removeTheTargetedBuildingX(event){
        var removeTheTargetedBuildingX = event.currentTarget;
        removeTheTargetedBuildingX.parentNode.removeChild(removeTheTargetedBuildingX);
    }
});
```

```css
#buildings{
  background-color: gray;
}

#first-building{
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#add-another-building{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: block;
}

.building-x{
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id='add-another-building'>Add another building</button>

<div id='buildings'>

<div id='first-building'></div><!--</first-building>-->

</div><!--</buildings>-->
```